# update with jquery

Tags: jquery, sql

I am making a small site, where I can put in a number in my form field. The number is saved in my MySQL database, and the value is return in a div where the id is "show". I have here made a jquery where the number is shown up immediately, so that is working fine.

I have now made another div tag where the id is "showhot". Here I would like to see the numbers between 1 - 100 that have been put in the most times. That is also working fine my SQL string, but the Jquery in it is not working. If I update my page, the numbers are moving up and down, if a specific number has been put in more times. I have tried to make some Jquery for it, but it is wrong.

Is there anybody who has a clue how I could do that?
I hope my question is understandable, otherwise I will reformulate it.

Best Regards
Mads

HTML:

```
<div id="show">
    <div class="numberheader">
        <p>Tal</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="latestnumbers" style="list-style:none;padding-top: 60px;">
        <?php include('response.php');?>
    </ul>           
</div>      



<div class="content">
    <p>Number</p>
    <div class="form">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Record Number</legend>
            <form id="myForm" action="select.php" method="post">
                <input type="number" name="numbervalue" id="numberinput"/>
                <button id="sub">Save</button>
            </form> 
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <span id="result"></span>
</div>



<div id="#showhot">         
    <div class="hotnumbersheader">
        <p>Hot</p>
    </div>  
    <ul class="hotnumbers" style="list-style:none; padding-top: 60px;">
        <?php include('hotnumbers.php');?>
    </ul>
</div>


<div id="#showhot">     
    <div class="coldnumbersheader">
        <p>Cold</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="coldnumbers" style="list-style:none; padding-top: 60px;">
        <?php include('coldnumbers.php');?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// Insert function for number
function clearInput() {
    $("#myForm :input").each( function() {
         $(this).val('');
    });
}

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#sub").click( function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); // remove default action(submitting the form) 
       $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
         $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
         function(info){            
         $("#result").html(info);
       });
       clearInput();
    });
    });

// Recieve data from database
$(document).ready(function() {
      setInterval(function () {
        $('.latestnumbers').load('response.php')
      }, 3000);
    });



/* *** THIS IS WHAT I HAVE BEEN TRYING TO MAKE, THAT IS NOT WORKING ****/
$(function () 
  {
   //Send a HTTP Request
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'hotnumbers.php',           //the script to call to get data          
      data: "dbconfig.inc.php",        //Url argumnets to pass to dbconnection
      dataType: 'json',                //data format      
      success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
      {
        var numbers = data[0];         //get numbers

        // 3) Update html content
        $('#showhot').html("<b>Number</b>"+numbers); //Set output element html
      } 
    });
  }); 


// Recieve data from database
$(document).ready(function() {
      setInterval(function () {
        $('hotnumbers').load('hotnumbers.php')
      }, 3000);
    });
```

hotnumbers.php

```
<?php
include ('session.php');
include 'dbconfic.inc.php';

    // '?' er placeholders for variabler
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT numbers FROM numbertable GROUP BY numbers ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 10;");

    // execute prepared statement 
    $stmt->execute();

    // Make variables ready 
    $number = null; 
    $n_id = null;

    // bind result variabler
    $stmt->bind_result( $number);

    // fetch values for each row
     while ($stmt->fetch()) {
         echo "<li>".$number."</li>";
     }  

    // close statement                      
    $stmt->close();

    // close connection
    $mysqli->close();       


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accidentally put a pound sign in the ID of your div in the HTML: `#showhot` when it should be `showhot`. Your polling code is missing a period in its selector: `$('hotnumbers')` instead of `$('.hotnumbers')`. It looks like you also have two divs with the same ID of `#showhot`. You probably meant for one of them to be `showcold`. I don't think that's causing any problems yet, though.